# What is the use of properties alternative accessors names in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties

In Objective-C properties you can set alternative names for the accessors.

```
@property(setter=nameWrite:,getter=nameRead,copy) NSString *name;
```

I am thinking real hard but I don't know any situation I would ever do that. It is not KVC standard and I see no advantage at all. What is the use of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly, it is used for BOOL properties:

```
@property(getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
@property(readonly, getter=isFinishedLaunching) BOOL finishedLaunching;
```

But, yeah, beyond that, it isn't used often at all (nor should it be).

Comment: Worth noting that this usage *is* KVC-compliant, as KVC will look for `isFoo` as well as `foo` for `BOOL` properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's seen all the time when you have a BOOL.

Ex:

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled;
```